# Facebook Graph API : list all domains

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

In the Facebook graph API reference https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0 there is not any link on how list domains associated to an user :/

This was possible with FQL (which will be deprecated) by requesting domain_admin table (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/domain_admin/).

Can anyone help me please ?

Thank you in advance,
Victor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
/{user-id}/domains
```

or:

```
/me/domains
```

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/domains/

Answer (score 0):

Just using

```
/domains
```

Appears to work but I cannot find it documented anywhere so far either.